# Mysql: disable unused schemas

Tags: mysql

I have many schemas on mysql instance running on my development pc. I've noticed that mysql is taking a large amount of ram and cpu time.

Is there a way to "disable" schemas of project I'm not working for?

I like to avoid to drop schema and then re-import when I need it. I'm searching to a way for just disable them or something similar!

Thanks 
Marco

Comment: Actually, if you have many databases, starting MySQL will not automatically put them in RAM... unless you explicitly set something like that up... which clearly you didn't... Have a look at MySQL configuration, maybe the cache sizes for InnoDB are too high or... something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every subfolder under `datadir` is considered fair game to be registered as a database. You could just mysqldump that entire database and then drop the database.

## SUGGESTION

If you have to leave the database present but inaccessible, here is something radical you can try:

EXAMPLE

Suppose you have a database called `mydb` and you want to disable access to it. Go into the Linux OS and do the following:

```
chown -R root:root /var/lib/mysql/mydb
```

That's it. Since `/var/lib/mysql/mydb` would be no longer owned by the Linux `mysql` user, mysqld cannot access anything in that folder.

If you want the database accessible again, just do the reverse:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/mydb
```

Now, if you are dealing with Windows, try shutting down mysql with

```
net stop mysql
```

You could then

- Rename the folder from `mydb` to `#mydb` something mysqld would not like
- Run `attrib` +a against that folder
- Just about anything that can deny read/write access to the Windows folder

Finally, start mysql back up

```
net start mysql
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I had not thought of this solution. I think it might be a good solution in my case! Thank you!

Comment: it is not working fine for me with phpmyadmin ... `mysql gone away`. However I found an alternative fix, now mysql takes 10 sec to boot with 20 Gb of databases and more than 5000 tables. In my scenario the issue was a debian script: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35092/mysql-disable-unused-schemas?newreg=ee569ab12ff641dd8891e8bf88175efe