# How does MySQL resolve schema information?

Tags: mysql, windows

I’ve used MySQL on windows7.

Recently my machine was infected by a virus.

After that `SHOW TABLES` and `SHOW DATABASES` statements don’t show any tables and databases but I can see data from tables which I’ve created with `SELECT` statement.

In addition `mysqldump` doesn’t work. It makes dump file but there is no data.

`mysqldump` can’t resolve database and table names.

I think `SHOW` statements and `mysqldump` use `information_schema` table.

Then my question is how does MySQL resolve schema information when it create `information_schema` table?

There must be some resource that `information_schema` refer to.

I believe the resource was destroyed by the virus,and I want to fix it.

Comment: you can check your data files. how much size it will be?

Comment: I think it'll be near 40GB.This size is from "ibdata" file under data directory.

Comment: Yes, I did. There are folders with same name of database I created and there are *.frm files with same name of tables in each folder.

Comment: I will also +1 the question since MySQL users in Windows must be made aware of the information_schema's sensitivity to the Windows environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a cause.
All folders under the data directory were hidden attribute.
I changed them then I can see tables and dump data.

Comment: This answer is actually brilliant. I was thinking the same for MySQL in Windows as I suggested how to disable databases using `attrib` just 2 days ago : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35096/877. +1 for discovering this not-so-well-known quirk.